# Does DSE search support aggregate involving CQL Solr-query

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I am trying to use DSE search for some basic reporting and need aggregate function like sum, count etc. 
want to know can I run aggregate queries involving CQL solr_query . Also which version of DSE?

Comment: Do you want to aggregate all data, or data for that you'll do "group by", etc.? Can you add example of queries that you plan to run?

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate queries are not supported in solr_query, only simple faceting. Please use the Solr HTTP JSON API for analytics functionality from Solr with DSE 5.1 and later.